# Working with BingSearchContainer.. But cant find .Web() method like in the tutorials..?

Tags: c#, bing-api

Im trying to use the Bing search Api according to a tutorial provided by Microsoft.
It looks like this:

```
        string query = "Xbox Live Games";
        string rootUrl = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search";
        var bingContainer = new BingSearchContainer(new Uri(rootUrl));
        string market = "en-us";
        bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("AccountKey", "AccountKey");
        var webQuery = bingContainer.Web(query, null, null, market, null, null, null, null);
        webQuery = webQuery.AddQueryOption("$top", 10);
        var webResults = webQuery.Execute();
        foreach (var result in webResults)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\n\t{1}", result.Title, result.Url);
        }
```

I have added the api as a service reference

[image]

And everything looks fine to me! But why oh why cant I use . .Web() method??
[image]

Comment: I count 8 parameters in the sample app... and only 7 parameters in your example. Make sure you have the exact number of parameters for function (i'm assuming its a fixed parameter count -- doesn't include "param")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is adding the url in the sample as a Service reference, instead of adding the proxy class which you can get from Microsoft. If you're looking at the same bing API tutorial I am, it says above the code sample:

*Creating a .NET Framework C# application is pretty easy. Most of the work that you need to do is handled for you by the Microsoft .NET Framework C# Service Proxy Class Library. You can download the service proxy for the Bing Search API by clicking the following link: https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/explore/getproxy/5ba839f1-12ce-4cce-bf57-a49d98d29a44.*

So, you need to download the proxy class and use that, not add the bing api as a service reference. Once you add the proxy class to your project, the sample will find the `bingContainer.Web` method and compile just fine:

[image: Proxy Class]

Hopefully this also goes without saying, but you'll need a valid account key -  `NetworkCredential("AccountKey", "AccountKey");` isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Any chance you can add a quick link to said tutorial? It sounds like this is exactly what I'm looking for...

Comment: Since they redesigned the site, I can't seem to find it anymore unfortunately.

Comment: I'm getting an Error The type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<TElement>' exists in both 'c:\Dev\..\packages\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.5.6.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll' and 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.Services.Client.dll' C:\Dev\..\BingSearchContainer.cs

Is there a specific nuget package for this? I seem to have two possible references to the referenced code in that class.

Comment: @StephenPrice You must remove one of the colliding assemblies from the references folder in your project, problaby System.Data.Services.Client.dl‌​l.